# UITextView text starts from the middle and not the top

Tags: swift, text, uitextview

I am having the same issue as others have and already posted in the forum. The text inside my texview starts from the middle and not from the top. I already tried some code that is provided in other posts but i have the same result. These are examples of what i used so far.

```
    self.maintext.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
    self.maintext.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0,1.0,0,0.0);
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

I tried them all by once and all together. The only result that i got was that my text was starting a little upper than without the code. Why is this happening? I tried also to change from the interface builder the view mode to TOP but still nothing.
I am loading the text from an rtf file. Could anyone give me an explanation of what is happening?  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ViewController containing the UITextField, add this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    textView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: :)

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        namesDescText.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
```